# Desktop shortcut gives error "KDEInit could not launch"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde-plasma, linux-mint

I am on Linux Mint KDE.

I created a c++ executable using Netbeans. Then I added the folder where the executable was to the path.

If I go to the terminal and run the executable it runs fine.

I next create a desktop file with the following

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Application;
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
Exec=myprog
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
Icon=utilities-terminal
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=Test
Name=Test
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

I change the permission of this desktop file to executable. If I double click the desktop file, I get a message saying "KDEInit could not launch 'myprog':
Could not find 'myprog' executable."

I wish to create a desktop shortcut to my executable. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to specify the path again in the desktop file?

Comment: Maybe the PATH variable have not been propagated until you restart X session ?

Comment: Could you elaborate. I couldn't understand, I am still a little new to linux

Comment: Isn't this clear ? Restart your window manager

Comment: Did it just now. Didn't work. I also tried changing the line Exec=myprog to Exec= konsole -e "myprog" then I get message saying "Warning: Could not find 'myprog', starting '/bin/bash' instead.  Please check your profile settings."

Comment: How do you call 'myprog' from within konsole ? With the full path or not ?

Comment: @sky: why don't you try with full path? Is your program put into the PATH, btw? You either need to place your executable in the PATH or use full path. There is no other way around to it.